# Error about the Redefinition of a struct and conflicting types for a function

Tags: c, function, struct, prototype, header-files

I have a given header (given1.h) file that includes my function prototypes, definitions, a struct definition, and libraries. I wanted to add a helper file called helper.h that incldues a function prototype called `int readDataFile(char fileName[30], struct Animal testData[NUM_TEST_DATA]);`

It would seem wise to add the prototype to given1.h but I must create a helper.h. Since the function prototype has struct Animal from given1.h and NUM_TEST-DATA, I need to add #include "given1.h", then include this both headers in both my main and function definition file.
Only problem is that when I do this, I get an error saying

```
error: redefinition of ‘struct Animal’
   31 | struct Animal {
      |        ^~~~~~
given1.h:31:8: note: originally defined here
   31 | struct Animal {
      |        ^~~~~~
given1.h:40:5: error: conflicting types for ‘readFromFile’; have ‘int(char *, struct Animal *)’
   40 | int readFromFile (char fName [30], struct Animal dataZoo [NUM_SAMPLES]) ;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
givenA1.h:40:5: note: previous declaration of ‘readFromFile’ with type ‘int(char *, struct Animal *)’
   40 | int readFromFile (char fName [30], struct Animal dataZoo [NUM_SAMPLES]) ;
```

and so on for all my functions. What can I do to fix this?

I did try putting my prototype within givenA1 and it gave me an implicit differentiation warning and still even then, it must go in helper.h. For some reason, the program only runs without warnings/errors when I put the prototype in main. I have zero idea as to why it only runs when the prototype is in main. How can I declare this prototype with the correct parameters from given1.h without causing an error regarding a redefintion of struct and an error regarding conflicting types for all functions. I also use a make file to compile it.

Comment: what about posting the code files???? Help others help you. Help others with your question.

Comment: Please read about how to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The struct redefinition errors are appearing because you're including given1.h in multiple places in a single translation unit (i.e. a source file, the headers it includes, the headers *those* include, etc) resulting in the struct definition appearing in multiple places.

You can fix this by adding *header guards* in your header files.  This prevents the contents from being included multiple times.  For example:

given1.h:

```
#ifndef GIVEN_H
#define GIVEN_H

struct Animal {
   ...

int readFromFile (char fName [30], struct Animal dataZoo [NUM_SAMPLES]) ;

...

#endif
```

Comment: So my prototype header file called helper.h has to have guards but does my given1.h? Since my prototype needs #define NUM_TEST_DATA 20 from given1.h and struct Animal, would I still write #include "given1.h" or does the logic around header guards prevent that?

Comment: @RelaxeddYeti, whether a given header's contents *need* to be protected from multiple inclusion depends on what they are.  But it is pretty common practice to skip the "need" question and just put guards in every header.  It's quick and easy, and the only way it can have any harmful side effects is if you mistakenly reuse the name of the guard macro.